# formtastic one to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many, formtastic

I have a model Driver which has many relationship to claims, I wish to have a form that client can enter their detail, together with a number of claims they've had in the past.

In the model, I have:

```
has_many :claims
```

and in the form I entered:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @driver do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  .......

  <%= f.inputs :for => :claims do |c| %>
    <% c.input :happen_date %>
    <% c.input :claim_details %>
    ...........
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

When I submit the form, the issue happens, I got Claim(#3213231311) expected, got Array(#70299228017580)

And I had a look at the form, I saw:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"VD3lt+LXZoA94YoL3PkI0frTH5EzT4vs/lZhzQhp0IQ=",
"driver"=>{
"name"=> "test tester",
.......
"claims"=>{"happend_date(3i)"=>"10",
"claim_date(2i)"=>"10",
"claim_date(1i)"=>"2012",
"claim_details"=>"dsadsadsadas"}},
"commit"=>"Next"}
```

Since there is a has_many relationship with the claims, shouldn't claims be covered in an array like:

```
"claims" => [{.....},{......}]
```

I've been working so hard on the form and still couldn't get claims to be send as array, anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Did you include this in your 'Driver' model:-

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :claims
```

Edit your form like :

```
<%= semantic_form_for @driver do |f| %> 
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.semantic_fields_for :claims do |c| %>
    <% c.input :happen_date %>
    <% c.input :claim_details %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Hope it will help. Thanks